# Error Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\where()

Tags: laravel

getting this error

Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\where()
https://bigsaledeals.com/checkout
Stack trace
Request
App
User
Context
Debug
Share

Collapse vendor frames
49
app/Http/Controllers/CheckoutController.php
App\Http\Controllers\CheckoutController
:641
48
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php
Illuminate\Routing\Controller
:54
47
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php
Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher
:45
46
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php
Illuminate\Routing\Route
:254
45
Illuminate\Routing\Route
:197
44
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php
Illuminate\Routing\Router
:695
43
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:128
42
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/EnsureEmailIsVerified.php
Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified
:30
41
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
40
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php
Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings
:50
39
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
38
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php
Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate
:44
37
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
36
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken
:78
35
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
34
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php
Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession
:49
33
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
32
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php
Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession
:121
31
Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession
:64
30
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
29
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php
Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse
:37
28
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
27
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php
Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies
:67
26
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
25
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:103
24
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php
Illuminate\Routing\Router
:697
23
Illuminate\Routing\Router
:672
22
Illuminate\Routing\Router
:636
21
Illuminate\Routing\Router
:625
20
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel
:166
19
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:128
18
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest
:21
17
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull
:31
16
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
15
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest
:21
14
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings
:40
13
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
12
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize
:27
11
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
10
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance
:86
9
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
8
vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php
Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors
:38
7
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
6
vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php
Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies
:57
5
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:167
4
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
:103
3
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel
:141
2
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel
:110
1
index.php
:55
App\Http\Controllers\CheckoutController::store
app/Http/Controllers/CheckoutController.php:641

```
                        'type' => 'order',

                        'order_id' => $orderSelf->id,

                        'currency_code' => Auth::user()->currency() ?? 'INR',

                      ]);

                  }

                  $itemvalue['promocode_id'] = null;

                  $itemvalue['referred_by'] = null;

                  $orderAll[] = $orderSelf->id;

                  if(sizeof($items)==1){

                    OrderTest::where('id', $orderSelf->id)->update(['parent_id' => $orderSelf->id]);

                  }

                }

            }



            if(sizeof($items)!=1){

                OrderTest: where('id', $orderSelf->id)->update(['parent_id' => $parentOrder->id]);

               $order = OrderTest::where('razorpay_orderid', $receiptId)->get();

            }

            else{

                $order = OrderTest::where('razorpay_orderid', $receiptId)->get();

            }



            if($orderSelf){

                Cartitem::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('cart_type','cart')->delete();

                if(Auth::user()->referred_by){

                  $user = Auth::user();

                  $user->referred_by = null;

                  $user->save();

                }

            }
```

when customer buys, item on checkout, customer should be taken to order page and email confirmation should be received to customer.

Comment: Can you share with us the line that got the error: CheckoutController :641 48?

Comment: This space. `OrderTest: where`

Comment: OrderTest: where('id', $orderSelf->id)->update(['parent_id' => $parentOrder->id]);

Answer (score 0):

```php
OrderTest: where('id', $orderSelf->id)->update(['parent_id' => $parentOrder->id]);
```

It should be:

```php
OrderTest::where('id', $orderSelf->id)->update(['parent_id' => $parentOrder->id]);
```

You have a colon `:` instead of the double colon `::` to call the static `where` method. The corrected line uses `OrderTest::where` instead of `OrderTest: where`.

Here's the corrected version:

```php
OrderTest::where('id', $orderSelf->id)->update(['parent_id' => $parentOrder->id]);
```

Make this change and check if it resolves the issue. If you have similar issues in other parts of your code, make sure to review and correct them as well.

Additionally, ensure that the `OrderTest` model is imported at the top of your `CheckoutController`:

```php
use App\Models\OrderTest;
```

Comment: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\where() still error

Comment: Do you Run composer dump-autoload ?